# Upgraded DL380 G2 To Windows Server 2008 and cannot locate network drivers - any advice?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, hp, hp-proliant, drivers

I was able to successfully load Windows Server 2008 on an HP DL380 G2, which is not officially supported by HP.  It seems to be working perfectly fine, except for the fact I cannot locate any network drivers that will work so I really cannot do anything with the server yet.  The server includes 2 HP NC3163 Fast Ethernet NIC's.  I've searched high and low for anything that could potentially make these NIC's work with Windows Server 2008, but haven't had any luck yet.

Should I quit my search and get a cheap gigabit card to put in one of the open PCI slots or is there some mysterious network driver resource I cannot locate?

Comment: Those use Intel chipsets if memory serves me.  You could try the Intel ProSet installer and see if that works?  might start here  http://www.intel.com/support/network/sb/cs-006120.htm

Comment: I looked at Intel website but didn't know what to try.  I'll give it a shot tomorrow!

Comment: Intel packages them all in one installer.  I don't know how far back the drivers go, but it's worth trying it.  But I think you might have better luck ditching them and getting PCI NICs instead.

Comment: That server doesn't belong in your datacenter. It _belongs_ in a _museum_!

Comment: I can't argue with that.  This is more of an experiment and won't be doing anything too important.  Running it till the wheels fall off!

Comment: This has to be Server 2008, because R2 requires 64 bit. That means you're running Vista when Windows 7 and 8 are out!

Comment: You are correct.  It is not R2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's sad... A [ProLiant DL380 G2](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/productbulletin.html#spectype=north_america&type=html&docid=10902) is a Pentium III server with 100-megabit NICs and Ultra3 *parallel* SCSI. It maxes-out at 6GB of RAM. :(

*These went away in 2002. Old-school.*

Luckily, the NIC is nothing special. It's just an Intel card. The Linux module/driver for the NC3163 card is the old standard Intel e100 or eepro100. The equivalent should work in Windows.

Try the Windows 2003 drivers for the [NC-Series NICs](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3288128&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_063e8a15ffa04a60a0b759145e%257CswEnvOID%253D1005%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) or the [NC31xx driver](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3288128&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_86e96bb805834445b13d2b8f2a%257CswEnvOID%253D1005%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken).

Comment: Old-school is right.  I'll give those driver suggestions a shot tomorrow.

Comment: Thinking on this further, as a general rule will many drivers stated to work with Windows Server 2003 also work with Windows Server 2008?